# Синтаксическая ошибка: Unexpected token п in JSON at position 0, раньше ее не было

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Отправляю на сервер `ajax` запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/manager_control_panel/get_nodes/deals/01-07-2019/All',
});
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token п in JSON at position 0

На сервере явно указал `http` заголовок тип документа `text/html`, хотя по умолчанию он у меня и так определяется как `html`.

Это серверная часть:

```
function get_node_list(){
    print 'привет';
}
```

Ожидаю, получить ответ в со словом привет. Ответ мне действительно приходит и я могу работать с полученной строкой, но дополнительно стала появляться и эта ошибка.

В чем можете быть дело? Не хочу указывать явно тип документа `json`, так как работаю не с массивом а именно с `html`, и не хотелось бы чтобы компактный `html` размазывался в 3-4 раза.

Попробовал написать вот так

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/manager_control_panel/get_nodes/deals/01-07-2019/All',
    dataType : 'html',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

ответ распечатался в консоль, но ниже все та же ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас `$.ajax` пытается конвертировать ответ в JSON. Укажите тип запроса при запрсое.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko дополнил вопрос

Comment: Не надо пробовать и тыкать в слепую. Почитайте документацию по работае с `$.ajax`  - у вас это займет полчаса. И узнаете много нового и интересного!

Comment: Посмотрите на какую строку вашего кода указывает ошибка. Возможно обработка json идет уже после ajax запроса, где-нибудь в другом месте. Плюс посмотрите заголовки, которые возвращает серверная часть. Мжб там указан json

Comment: @Skywave самое интересно что у меня все файлы в которых написан ajax стали выдавать эту ошибку...
Буду искать источник. Уже нашел, в другом файле была порписана функция которая реагировала на любой ajax/ Ну и в  ней соответственно был прописан тип данных на прием в виде json